# Create lotus notes New Calendar Entry via C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

[image]I was successfully able to open new Appointment through C# code, but for some reason Who field is not editable. I would like to just open the new Calendar Entry through C# program with given dates, and let the user fill in Subject, Attendees, Location etc.

```
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Appointment");
 //Type of the appointment, means:
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("AppointmentType", "Meeting");

 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", "");

 // Set Confidential Level (Public=1 or Private=0) 
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("$PublicAccess", "1");
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("$ExpandGroups", "3");
 //Add Start&End Time of your event
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("CALENDARDATETIME", StartDate);
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("StartDateTime", StartDate);
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("EndDateTime", EndDate);
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("StartDate", StartDate);
 //Infos in The Body
 LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Body", "");
 LNDocument.ComputeWithForm(true, false);
 LNDocument.Save(false, false, false);


 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(LNDocument.NotesURL);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code. What do the declaration and assignment of LNDocument look like?  You also need to give more info. What do you mean by "the Who field"? Calendar appointments in Lotus Notes don't have a Who field as far as I know. And what do you mean by "not editable"? What are you trying do do? Is your code trying to edit the appointment, or are you saying that a user is not able to edit the appointment in the Notes client after you create the appointment in your code. Perhaps a screenshot would help.

Comment: edited the post with initialize code. Who field means "Required Attendees". the field is not displayed at all. If you use plain lotus notes and do new Meeting, it will display three sections When,Who, Where, so basically, I want to invoke same new meeting with "When" information thru c# program.

Comment: Okay, so it's a Meeting. Your meeting has no Chair.  I believe it's the case that only the Chair can edit the Required Attendees list.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that the new Document (Calendar Entry) is not in Edit Mode? Because with LNDocument.Save(....) you save the document and after saving normally the document is not in Edit-Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
meetingChair = "fully distinguished name of the person who owns the meeting"; 
LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Chair", meetingChair);
```

Only the listed person will be able to edit the attendees.  Presumably, it's the name of the person in whose mail database you are saving the meeting.